# htaccess разрешить доступ к папке

Tags: .htaccess, доступ

Мне надо в файле htaccess разрешить доступ напрямую к папке ftp, причем нужно чтобы работало и `Options -Indexes`. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разместите внутри папки ftp файл .htaccess с таким содержанием. Это откроет доступ ко всем внутреним папкам и файлам

```
Options -Indexes
Order Deny,Allow 
Allow from all
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
видает после добавление в htaccess

Comment: изменил решение - то что сейчас написано протестировал на своем сервере - работает.... настройки внутри папки перекрывают настройки в главном .htaccess, в котором вы запрещаете доступ ко всем папкам